# ceiling fan from a switch with only black and red wires?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

The current switch controls an outlet in the corner of the room for a lamp. I pulled it out and noticed three sets of individual wires: two set of wires coming up into the box from the bottom, and one set with a red wire coming down into box.  All the white and grounding wires are capped.  Also all the black wires are capped; one set I’m assuming is the hot since I see it contains a red wire. On the back of the switch, the top two ports have black wires and the bottom right has the one red wire.  There are two black pigtail wires coming off the black capped wires.

I tried to connect a separate switch to control a ceiling fan with remote. I ran new wire making the old switch box into a two switch. I ran 14/2 gauge wire to ceiling for fan / light remote combo. Fan didn’t work after multiple re-wiring  combinations. The breaker did pop and half click when it popped. Then I thought to re-wire the ceiling fan wires as if I was going to make it into outlet only and use a tester to indicate an open ground, or a wiring error but the two light on tester are both orange indicating correct wiring.

I heard that sometimes the ceiling fan remote transformer goes bad. Should I check batteries and/or unit placement?

I’m really confused at this point why the light is not working at least with remote after follow wiring installation instructions that were included with the fan.

I think it’s my wiring with the switch. The way I left the wiring is that it has constant power. As if we’re a outlet the current switch does not turn it off.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the switch box please?

Comment: More information should be provided. If you in NA, red wire means the cable has 3 wires, so white is neutral, black and red phase. Important to know where is another sides of those cables. You probably have 2 3-way switches.

Comment: Word to the wise: Adding a question mark to a statement doesn't do much but confuse your reader--we don't know if you're telling or asking. Either ask a question or make a statement. Don't mash them together. I've done some editing. If it's not accurate, please revise further, but try to be more clear and specific. This isn't creative literature class and your health is at stake.

Comment: What are "sets of individual wires"? Are those cables, or do you have conduit?

Comment: Thanks for your replies

Comment: Thanks for your replies I need to go back to the house a take better pictures in regards to your questions  and to note how the wires are grouped ? As to not confuse.  appreciate any feedback give me two days please .